# Integrate 3D sensing in robot_localization package

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I came across of this image of the robot_localization package, and I wonder if it is possible to integrate in the sensor fusion the 3D sensing data like in the picture. I didn't find anything about incorporating 3D sensing data in the documentation of this package.

Best,

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330821/integrate-3d-sensing-in-robot_localization-package/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2019-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) is just a kalman filter that fuses odometry data to provide a filtered estimate of the fusion of sensors. The package can currently accept messages of type:

- [Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)
- [IMU](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html)
- [Pose](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html)
- [Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistWithCovarianceStamped.html)

from a plethora of sources. Where those sources come from is up to you. The package does have support for 3D localization and 2D localisation with `two_d_mode` set to true. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html) as to how to use this. Specifically referring to your picture,

- Odometry would be supplied from a tachometer relating the sensor to kinematic constraints
- IMU would come from an Inertial Measurement Unit of which the manufacturer most likely provides a driver
- GPS provides a pose in a global reference frame which is determined by the [navsat_transform_node](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html) also a part of the package.
- Camera using some visual odometry package such as [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Visual_and_Lidar_Odometry) or [viso](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros)
- 3D sensing appears to represent an [Xbox Kinect](http://wiki.ros.org/kinect) in this image of which you could perform the above visual odometry or even [Iterative Closest Point](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#icp_odometry) (ICP) odometry by interpreting the depth sensing as a point cloud

Based on the sources you supply to the state estimation nodes, it will provide a 3D (or 2D) estimate of your position. This package is often used in collaboration with [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) for Simaltaneous Localisation And Mapping (SLAM).

Thanks, Grant.

---

Originally posted by [PapaG](https://answers.ros.org/users/40565/papag/) with karma: 161 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3